# How to go another screen via menu

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a menu (Fack Call, Fake SMS, Statistic & About).
I want this text with an icon.
I tried, but it didn't work.
I also want to move to another screen when I click Fack Call, Fake SMS, Statistic text.

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.call:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FakeCall.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.sms:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.statistic:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "statistic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return true;

        case R.id.about:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "about", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

FackCall.java

```
public class FakeCall extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fakecall);
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:icon="@drawable/fakecall"
        android:title="@string/call"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sms"
        android:icon="@drawable/fakesms"
        android:title="@string/sms"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statistic"
        android:icon="@drawable/statistic"
        android:title="@string/statistic"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/about"
        android:title="@string/about"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: _it doesn't work_ What doesn't work? The text with the icon. Or the new Activities don't open?

Comment: both (text and new activities) :D

Comment: Code seems correct, what is happening when you click? Just out of curiosity why you have `@SuppressWarnings` before `onOptionsItemSelected`? I don't believe it has been deprecated.

Comment: I don't understand exactly about this (@SuppressWarnings) If you have a time, please explain me. Now, I check the code and remove it. that is OK .... I need when I click on text, I want to go another activity related text.

Comment: What happens when you click on `call`? `@SuppressWarnings` is used to suppress the warnings created by the compiler while compiling the code. This may be due to many reasons such as a `deprecated` function, etc. So, by adding `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` over the function you tell the compiler to not to bother you with `deprecation` stuff while compiling the code.

Comment: I tried your code, it is working fine at my end. What exactly is your problem? What happens when you click on the menu? Do `Toast` appear?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}'
```